# EWS issues Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

This similar question has been asked before but none of them solve my problem as I've tried all of their solutions already.

I am trying to connect to send an email through my email address. I've fixed as many issues as I could, but I couldn't find where to fix this one. Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

        //Set up Credentials
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(emailAddress, password);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        service.Url = new Uri("https://example.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        //service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        service.TraceEnabled = true;


        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
        email.ToRecipients.Add(emailAddress);
        email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
        email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API.");
        email.Send();
```

I get one error:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'
```

and three 'inner exceptions':

```
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Using AutodiscoverUrl also returned an error:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException: 'The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.'
```

All other posts recommended I change the security protocol, but this did not change anything and those posts are very old now.
I saw in many places that I should enable tracing to help me debug the issue, but I couldn't find how to view the trace logs after I make them. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See [The Autodiscover service couldn't be located](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/329488/the-autodiscover-service-couldn39t-be-located.html).

Comment: I already implemented that line into my ode, but it did not fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see the actual error message?

Comment: No, how would I use Fiddler to do that? I have never used Fiddler before

Comment: I do get this when I output the error to a text file:

https://pastebin.com/85C0nw1k

Comment: > System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Comment: You may get this error when trying to call an external API. This error is related to the Security Protocol Type, it is most likely caused by your application's default security protocol type being set too low, A lot of external APIs now expect requests using TLS 1.2 or above.